# Como mostrar 'algo' al hacer click en un boton con React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jsx

Quiero hacer que cuando le damos click al boton 'Haceme click' te muestre el titulo en este caso:

## Hola Mundo

Pero no estaria mostrando nada y no entiendo por que.
Solamente me funciona si retorno con console.log o con alert, pero si quiero retornar algun titulo(h1) o algun div no me funciona

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js">
export default function Descomposicion() {
    return (

        <div>
            <StyleCSS></StyleCSS>
            <Botton></Botton>

        </div>


    )
    
}


function handleClick () {
    return (
        <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    )
}

function Botton (props) {
    return (
        <button onClick={StyleCSS}>Haceme click</button>
    )
}

class StyleCSS extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <h1 style={
                {
                    color: "royalblue",
                    backgroundColor:"yellowgreen"
                }
            }>Hola</h1>
        )
    }
}

</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del estado del componente para mostrar u ocultar elementos, aquí un ejemplo:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showTitle: false };
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showTitle: true })}>Click</button>
            {this.state.showTitle && (
              <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la documentación oficial de React https://es.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba seguire investigando!

Answer (score -1):

Al botón en la cual se le hace click, debe tener:

```
<button onClick="handleClick()"></button>
```

Comment: Lo he intentado de esa forma y me sigue sin retornar lo que tengo en la funcion handleCLick

Comment: no te funciona por que no es un simple html, en react se trabaja con jsx, deberias investigar la documentacion para saber mas sobre el mismo